# Rails mailer: create object and access the id of the object inside a mailer view template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating and object inside a controller:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  if @item.save
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to index_path, notice: "Created"}
      format.json { render :'shows/show', status: :created, location: @item }
     end
      ModelMailer.delay.new_post(@user)
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

this is the mailer method:

```
def new_post(user)
  @user = User.find(user.id)
  attachments.inline["logo.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.png")
  mail(:to => @follow.email,
     :subject => "Created a new post")
end
```

I would like to add the `item.id` thats is created to the mailer so I can access it in the email view template. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it. I don't actually see where you save the record so presumably your `create` example is incomplete, but once you have that working you can do...

```
ModelMailer.new_post(@user, @item.id).deliver_later
```

Then on the mailer

```
def new_post(user, item_id)
  @item_id = item_id
```

The `@item_id` will be available in the view.

And to fix your controller `create` method (which is still wrong), it should be...

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  if @item.save
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to index_path, notice: "Created"}
      format.json { render :'shows/show', status: :created, location: @item }
      ModelMailer.delay.new_post(@user, @item.id)
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SteveTurczyn... I'm receiving the email but `@item_id` in the view is empty.

Comment: the `if @item.save` was there i just deleted it by mistake when I was adding the code tom my question. So again, nothing shows up.

Comment: Modify the line in controller where you trigger the mailer from `ModelMailer.delay.new_post(@user)` to       `ModelMailer.delay.new_post(@user, @item.id)`

Comment: And where's the `end` for the `respond_to` block?

Comment: Yeah I deleted that one too by mistake... but its there. Anyway still the same result, blank .